# I have been asked to calculate a raise, should I ask based on my needs or to match my colleagues?

Tags: salary, raise

I've been recommended to calculate a raise based on my needs, and based on the average market salaries for my experience and job.
Doing this leads me to a figure that is significantly lower than the salary of some colleagues.

A part of myself tells me to ignore others' salary while the other part feels it would not be fair as I've had lots of feedback telling me I'm on par or better than some of said colleagues.

**Would it be appropriate to ask for a bigger raise to match my colleagues ?**

Comment: Doesn't the salary of your colleagues factor in as a sort of "local" market rate?

Comment: @gnat This isn't the same at all,  OP is being given the chance to calculate their raise based on their needs. They're already being offered a raise, not approaching for one.

Comment: This is completely your choice, the obvious answer to me is to match your colleagues, why sell yourself short.

Comment: Note that sometimes a higher salary is kind of a golden cage: as you salary raises, you get new habits, new loans, you create yourself new needs. Then with all this, if at some point you're not happy anymore with your current job you  will need to find another job paying (almost) the same, and if you current salary is much hight than the average, this might become very challenging. And there goes the vicious circle: the more you stay in a company, the less desirable and up-to-date you become to the others. So basically you can't afford to move, and nobody wants you. You're stuck...

Comment: *I've had lots of feedback telling me I'm on par or better than some of said colleagues.* Who did this feedback come from? By "better" did they mean "better at everything" or "better at [specific task]"?

Comment: @BSMP feedback came from direct manager and many of the team members I manage myself. Most of the comments were mentionning the production value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should I ask a raise to fit my needs or to match my colleagues?

### No.

You should do this based on **data** to support your claim as to what *you* are worth.  A few google searches should provide this information.  Be prepared for your employer to possibly say **no** too, if you ask for too much.

I would **not** approach this from the perspective of "*my colleagues make X*" either.  It may come across as *petty*.  The **only** way your salary compared to your colleagues is relevant is if you are similar (near exact) in *experience, seniority, productivity, and capabilities*.  Even then I would not use this strategy.

This is about what **you** are worth, and **why**.

Comment: If his colleagues are being paid X, and he is as valuable as they are, why isn't he worth X?  Isn't his colleagues salaries "data"?

Comment: @DaveG Because they are not the same worker.  Just because 2 people do the same job doesn't necessarily mean they are worth the same dough.  Often times they are not.

Comment: True, but if the OP just googles what the local salaries are, what evidence is there that he is worth more or less than the average in the area?  At least when he compares to people in his own company, he can match up experience, job title, length of service, etc.

Comment: @DaveG there are plenty of sites that provide trusted data as to what you are worth based on many factors such as industry, experience, certifications, education, etc.  There are many factors that go into determining an employees worth not just the fact that they do the same job.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be appropriate to ask for a bigger raise to match my colleagues?

Only if you

1. have a similar title
2. with similar seniority
3. with similar responsibilities
4. produce similar quality of work, and
5. are happy with that salary

**But this is not the question you're asking**. What you're asking is, *Can I justify a salary quote based on the salary of my colleagues?*

To that, the answer is: **you don't have to justify anything**. If you begin to justify your price, you're inviting the other party to get you to lower it.

With that in mind I answer to you: Get your colleague's salary, add 15% as a safety net, and run with it. The average salary in your area shouldn't apply to you, because you have insider knowledge that is - presumably - valued.

Comment: "If you begin to justify your price, you're inviting the other party to get you to lower it." yep... also it's an open calculation 'your needs' can be anything and could include 'I need to make as much as my colleagues to be happy'